# Using the delve debugger with go modules

Tags: go, debugging, delve

Take a look at this directory structure:

```
/root
    /bar
        go.mod
        go.sum
        main.go
        main_test.go
    /foo
        go.mod
        go.sum
        main.go
        main_test.go
```

I'd like to debug `root/foo/main.go` using the delve debugger from the command line. I've tried building the binary using `go build`, and then using `dlv debug <binary>` with errors like:

```
can't load package: package foo is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/foo)
exit status 1
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `root` has two different modules in it, `foo` and `bar`. You can't use `go build` from `root` to build them, because `go build` doesn't support nested or multiple modules. You have to run it from the directory `go.mod` is in, or any of its child directories.

Since Delve simply calls `go build` for you, the same applies with `dlv debug`. Try to `cd` into `foo` first, and then run `dlv debug`.

Comment: I did a `go build` in the correct directory, but for some reason, `dlv` didn't work when I explicitly gave it the built binary (maybe something having to do with nested modules?). Simply typing `dlv debug` in the module I wanted to debug worked, thanks!